# Obtain $L^\infty$ estimate of Poisson Equation only using eigenfunction expansion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ a bounded domain with sufficient smooth boundary. We consider the Poisson Equation
$$\left\{\begin{array}
--\Delta u = f, & \Omega\\
u=0, &\partial\Omega\end{array}\right.$$

Let $\{\lambda_n,\phi_n\}$ to be eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of Dirichlet Laplacian. Let $\mu_n=\frac{1}{\lambda_n}$. Assume $f\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ and $f=\sum_n^\infty a_n\phi_n$, the decay of $a_n$ is sufficiently fast. The solution must be $u=\sum_n^\infty \mu_n a_n \phi_n$.

My question is: can we obtain the $L^\infty$ estimate: $\|u\|_\infty\leq C\|f\|_\infty$ , only using the above eigenfunction expansion?( If we can prove the uniform bound for sufficient smooth function, then by density argument the estimate would hold for all $f\in C(\Omega)$.

At first I tried the case when $\Omega=(0,1)^2$, since the eigenfunction expansion is just Fourier expansion. But it's still hard to do the estimate. I can show that $a_n$ is bounded by $\|f\|_\infty$, but $\mu_n=\frac{1}{4\pi^2|\vec{n}|^2}$, and $\sum_n \mu_n$ diverges, thus we cannot simply estimate $a_n$ as $\|f\|_\infty$ in the summation. Can anyone help me with this problem, or simply the case of $\Omega=(0,1)^2$? Thanks!

Comment: Omitting constants, $$\|u\|_{\infty} \leq \|u\|_{H^{-d/2 - h}} \leq \|f\|_{H^{-d/2 - h - 2}} \leq \|f\|_{L^2} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$$

Comment: Thanks! @Mason , but can you explain the first inequality? Sorry I'm not quite familiar with $H^{-s}$ space, I only remember that $\|u\|_\infty \le C \|u\|_{H^s}$ for $s>d/2$.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I made a mistake. We still get an estimate for $d< 4$.

Comment: Sorry again, I'm still confused, @Mason, can you explain why the estimate holds for $d<4$? The exponent $-\frac{d}{2}-h$ is still negative.

Comment: My comment is wrong. You should use $$\|u\|_{\infty} \leq \|u\|_{d/2 + h} \leq \|f\|_{d/2 - 2 + h} \leq \|f\|_{L^2} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$$ provided $d/2 - 2 + h \leq 0$, i.e. $d \leq 4 - 2h$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!